# jquery tableeditor

Tags: jquery

im trying jquery tableeditor (http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/tableEditor/demo.php), but it doesn't work. I m using jquery-1.4.2, and i see tableeditor recommend 1.0.3, does it mean it won't work in jquery 1.4.2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wow that's oldschool! I wouldn't expect it to work, there are much better solutions, i like [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) for example.